# facebook-python-ads-sdk - ImportError: cannot import name 'objects'

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I installed facebookads according to the README.md (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk)

```
pip3 install facebookads
```

Then I tried to import facebookads in my python code according to the README.md.

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects
```

Then the following error appeared

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_facebook_campaigns.py", line 2, in <module>
    from facebookads import objects
ImportError: cannot import name 'objects'
```

I also tried git clone and ran the setup.py to install the module, but the result was the same.

How can I remove this error?

versions: python 3.5.2, pip 9.0.1, facebookads 2.9.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the new versions 2.8.2 (19 days old) and 2.9.1 (8 days old) introduced this import error. Using version 2.8.1 doesn't give me this error:

```
$ pip install -I facebookads==2.8.1
...
$ python
>>> from facebookads import objects
>>>
```

They could have changed the library without changing the documentation.
The file `objects.py` which existed in older versions seems to [have been removed](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/commit/5a01e17a103df3d549bcf2edd793789cd321fab5#diff-81). The top of the file had the examplanation:

```
-This file is kept for backward compatibility.
-Please use objects in adobjects folder instead.
```

So in the new import would look as follows:

```
from facebookads.adobjects.<file> import <object>
# or
from facebook.adobjects import <file>
<file>.<object>
```

Looking at the old [objects.py](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/9f9be04959a5b00d699d306bb0266cc58b6aec30/facebookads/objects.py) file shows us which file and object we need. For example for the old `objects.Campaign` object we use the following `campaign.Campaign` object:

```
from facebookads.adobjects import campaign
c = campaign.Campaign(...)
```